# Running stored procedure from Windows Service ad hoc access error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm attempting to run a stored procedure that processes an excel file for import from a Windows Service developed in C#. I can run the stored procedure directly in SQL Server Management Studio, but when running the stored procedure through the service I get the following error;

> Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' has been denied. You must access this provider through a linked server.

`Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` is listed in `Server Object\Linked Servers\Providers`, additionally, `Disallow adhoc access` is unchecked in the Provider Options.

I don't know what else to try. Any thoughts? TIA

**EDIT**: added some service code

```
public ProcessFile(string fileName)
{
        this.fileName = fileName;
        fileToProcess = Properties.Settings.Default.importFilePath + "\\" + fileName;

        log.Debug("fileToProcess: " + fileToProcess);

        OpenExcelFile();

        excelSheets = getSheetNames();

        excelWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(2);

        log.Debug("sheet Name: " + excelWorkSheet.Name);

        connectToDb();

        CloseExcelFile();
}

private void connectToDb()
{
        int retVal = db.LoadSPVDataSheet(Properties.Settings.Default.importFilePath, this.fileName, excelWorkSheet.Name);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm using SQL Server 2012 running on Windows Server 2012 R2

[image: SQL server Registry entries]
[image: SSMS Provider Dialog]

**EDIT 3**
I found the entry for `AllowInProcess`, and the Disallow Adhoc entry wasn't there.  It was located @:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WOW6462Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS11.<ServerName>\Providers\MSOLAP
```

I'm going add the entry and report back.

**EDIT 4**

The service code is now connecting and processing correctly.  I found another place where the`DisallowAdHocAccess` registry key was missing.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WOW6462Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.<ServerName>\Providers\Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

I added the key there, and it worked.

Comment: Is your C# using that driver? It's easier for people to help if you post your code.

Comment: @JacobH I added some of the service code.  I don't know what else I need to provide.

Comment: Take a look at the following post from over on DBA stackexchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61739/help-with-sql-server-error-ad-hoc-access-to-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this connect item: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/257494/smss-does-not-handle-the-provider-option-disallowadhocaccess-correctly
or read the detailes explained here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4582/sql-server-ad-hoc-access-to-ole-db-provider-has-been-denied-error/
"We can disable "Disallow adhoc access" from the SSMS provider properties, but it removes the entry in the registry instead of changing the value to zero and we still get the ad hoc access to OLE DB provider has been denied error."
So you should manually add the missing entry in registry and enter 0 in it